# 90's (?) chapter book: young boy creates a computer clone, switch places

Tags: story-identification, books, computers

I read this book back in Elementary School in the 90s.

The young boy doesn't exactly like school so he makes himself a computer clone and they switch places and the clone goes to school and starts liking life outside of the computer and won’t switch places back.

The cover was of a boy typing on the computer and you see his clone coming through the computer screen.

Answer (score 3):

Is it [*The Duplicate*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/24884.The_Duplicate)? Originally published in 1988, a science fiction novel for young adults written by William Sleator.

> When David finds a mysterious machine that can copy living things, he thinks his problems are over. By duplicating himself, he can visit his grandmother and keep his date with Angela. While the other David is in school, the real one can spend the day at the beach. The possibilities are endless... and terrifying.
> What begins as the solution to David's problems soon turns into a nightmarish struggle for identity. Then events take a horrifying turn that neither of the two Davids can control and that may have deadly consequences.

*The young boy doesn't exactly like school so he makes himself a computer clone and they switch places*

> When David finds a mysterious machine that can copy living things, he thinks      his problems are over. Now he can be in two places at once: at his grandmother's and out on a date.
>
> <sub>[Amazon.com, *The Duplicate* (Novel)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0141304316)</sub>

*the clone goes to school and starts liking life outside of the computer and won’t switch places back.*

> While the other David is in school, the real one can spend the day at the beach. The possibilities are endless. And they turn terrifying. David's duplicate has a mind, ideas, and desires of his own--and one of them is to see the real David dead.
>
> <sub>ibid</sub>

Comment: I added in an extra source for more information and added the link to Amazon. I also reversed the quote markdown so it's easier to see what is from an off site resource. Feel free to roll back my changes if you want.